# Edit CSS if Text Input empty on Submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

This is my HTML form:

```
<form action="process.php" id="login" method="POST">
<p>Username: <?php echo $form->error("user"); ?></p>
<div>
<input type="text" style="font-size: 13px; color: #7e7e7e;" autocomplete="off" id="user" name="user" maxlength="18" length="18" value="<?php echo $form->value("user"); ?>">
</div>
<p>Password: <?php echo $form->error("pass"); ?></p>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="<?php echo $form->value("pass"); ?>">
<p>Email:</p>
<?php echo $form->error("email"); ?>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $form->value("email"); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="fav_continent" value="Default">
<input type="hidden" name="fav_colour" value="Default">
<input type="hidden" name="subjoin" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Here's my custom style for the text input field:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: all .3s; 
}
```

It looks like this in JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/qzrtccLx/

If a user submits the form and either one of the text input fields is empty, how do I make the **EMPTY** text input field's change from `border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;` to `border-bottom: 1px solid red;`?

Comment: You write some javascript. You've attempted to write no code. This is easy.

Comment: I mean easy in the sense of easy to look up on Google. Or even on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a answer in pure JavaScript. I've written an event to check all the inputs when the form is submitted. If there are any values that are empty, then I update the class on the input and prevent the form from submitting.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("login");
login.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  var valid = true;
  var inputs = login.querySelectorAll("input");
  [].forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    if (input.value === "") {
      valid = false;
      input.classList.add("error");
    }  
  });
  
  if (!valid)
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: all .3s; 
}

input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]), input[type=password]:focus:not([readonly]), input[type=email]:focus:not([readonly]) {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #26a69a;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #26a69a; 
}

input[type=text].error {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form action="process.php" id="login" method="POST">
  <p>Username: </p>
  <div>
    <input type="text" style="font-size: 13px; color: #7e7e7e;" autocomplete="off" id="user" name="user" maxlength="18" length="18">
  </div>
  <p>Password:</p>
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
  <p>Email:</p>
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="hidden" name="fav_continent" value="Default">
  <input type="hidden" name="fav_colour" value="Default">
  <input type="hidden" name="subjoin" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute we can use the [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ainvalid) pseudo class. The Snippet won't demonstrate this behaviour with PHP so I have emitted it all.

```css
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: all .3s; 
}
input[type=text]:invalid {
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<form action="process.php" id="login" method="POST">
<p>Username: </p>
<div>
<input type="text" style="font-size: 13px; color: #7e7e7e;" autocomplete="off" id="user" name="user" maxlength="18" length="18" value="" required>
</div>
<p>Password: </p>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="">
<p>Email:</p>
<input type="text" name="email" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="fav_continent" value="Default">
<input type="hidden" name="fav_colour" value="Default">
<input type="hidden" name="subjoin" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using jQuery, you should use jQuery's [submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) function to handle the form submit. This function also handles the actual form submission. `return true;` to submit and `return false;` to halt submission.

```
$("#login").submit(function() {
    $(this).find("input[type='text']").each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
             $(this).css("border-bottom", "1px solid red");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He's not using jQuery.

Comment: For one reason or another, this isn't working - the border-bottom isn't changing to red..

Comment: @IainProctor Did you include jquery in your header?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JS to intercept the form's submission by attaching an event listener.

```
var form = document.getElementById('login');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    //Code here
}, false);
```

Then inside the function, find all the input fields and loop through each one.

```
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    //Check each input value individually
}
```

Then inside the loop, check if the value of the input is empty. If so, Give it a red border and cancel the form submission.

```
if(inputs[i].value=='') {
    inputs[i].style.borderBottom = '1px solid red';
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Take a look at this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzrtccLx/7/)

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery `.val()` and a `submit` event handler

For example

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
   if($('input').val() == ''){
        $('input').css('border-bottom:', '1px solid red');
   }
})
```

Comment: It is a suggestion, not the entire answer.